# What are the major differences between kohana 3.0.x and 3.1.0?

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, php

I noticed they have separate documentation but it is still very weak. I have noticed a couple changes but nothing I think would require a separate documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the changes you need to be aware of are listed here: [Migrating from 3.0.x](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/kohana/upgrading)